# What does the "cxa" prefix mean in "__cxa_demangle"?

Tags: c++, linux, prefix

I have a piece of code, in which I see the `__cxa_` prefix. For instance, the following excerpt contains it:

```
    std::unique_ptr<char, void (*)(void *)> own(
#ifndef _MSC_VER
            abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(TR).name(), nullptr,
                                nullptr, nullptr),
#else
            nullptr,
#endif
            std::free
    );
```

I would be happy to have some explanations on the meaning of `cxa`.

Comment: I would guess the "x" is for "extended" and the "a" for "abi". Then referring to Intel's ABI, if I recall correctly. No idea about the "c".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just function name, but may be it's `CXxAbi`.